# Facebook can't get permission to email and public_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I create new App and I want to use oauth to login via Facebook on my page. My other two App work correct but in this new I see:

```
Your app has standard access to public_profile. To use Facebook Login, switch 
public_profile to advanced access. Get Advanced Access
```

and in settings for facebook login next to the email and public_profile fields it says **"verification required"** even for standard permissions ...

Someone knows what's going on?

ANSWER:

**It seems like Facebook now demand business verification for "facebook login" to work. Two days after uploading company documents, facebook login started working.**

Comment: the whole company is dumb for doing that it is like unity